# Page not displaying previous selected value from a dropdown list in a for loop - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to make a dynamic form with a `DropDownList` to select values

In the view, I have this:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.SelectedIntensities.Count(); i++)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @(i + 1)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedIntensities, new SelectList(Model.Filter.Intensities, Model.SelectedIntensities.ElementAt(i)))
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

This i working quite fine while retrieving the data with the `SelectedIntensities` parameter in my controller.

After that I set the values back in my ViewModel

```
vm.SelectedIntensities = selectedIntensities.ToList();
```

But then in my view if I had more than one dropdownlist, they take the value of the first one as `SelectedValue`.

So if I select two different intensities from the two dropdown : **20** and **25** for example. When I submit my form and the page is reloaded with the values both dropdown will display **20** as selected value...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the property your trying to bind to? Your currently trying to bind the selected value to a list. It should be something like `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedIntensities[i].SomeProperty, ...`.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I think you just solved my problem, the `SelectedIntensities` was an `ICollection`, with the `SelectedIntensities[i]` the intensities are correctly displayed now.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl you were right too, the id/name was indeed the same for both dropdowns, thanks a lot guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by Stephen in the comments the solution was to specify the index of the `SelectedIntensities`

I replaced this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedIntensities, new SelectList(Model.Filter.Intensities, Model.SelectedIntensities.ElementAt(i)))
```

With this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedIntensities[i], new SelectList(Model.Filter.Intensities))
```

It works perfectly now.